# Remove "save draft" button on mod messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

When sending a moderator message, there is a button "Save draft" as shown here:

[image]

However, this does not work or at least, the draft is not user recoverable if it does get saved somewhere.

My suggestion would be to just remove the "save draft" button, as it is quite misleading to have a button that does not work but seems to. I normally save message drafts elsewhere but occasionally do forget; for newer moderators this probably is a learning experience everyone has at least once.

If you are writing a message you need to save it's also normally a message which requires some work.

- Please remove this "save draft" button from both a new and reply mod message

(or if it's easier to fix to work correctly, that'd be fine :) )

Comment: Yeah, your last line would be better, but if it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been removed and the change will apply as of build 3737 on MSE/MSO and build 2860 on other sites.

Comment: Sweet! nom nom filler nom. Thanks :)